# Sorting a JavaDStream - Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, dstream

I have an application which works with `JavaDStreams` objects. 
This is a piece of code, where I compute the frequencies the words appear with.

```
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(
      new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
          return new Tuple2<>(s, 1);
        }
      }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
          return i1 + i2;
        }
      });
```

Now, if I wished to print the top N frequent elements, sorted by the Integer value, how can I do this if there's not methods like [sortByKey](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#sortByKey()) (for JavaPairRDD)?

Comment: You can implement the method by yourself.

Comment: Yes, I thought of a workaround, but that would not allow me to work with JavaDStreams, they would just be RDDs.

Comment: I think for streaming the data is coming continously,it's hard to sort them.But you can save them before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have `JavaPairDStream<String, Integer>` and want to sort by Integer value, you have to swap pair first.

```
JavaPairDStream<Integer,String> swappedPair = wordCounts.mapToPair(x -> x.swap());
```

Now you can sort by using `transformToPair` and use `sortByKey` function.

```
JavaPairDStream<Integer,String> sortedStream = swappedPair.transformToPair(
     new Function<JavaPairRDD<Integer,String>, JavaPairRDD<Integer,String>>() {
         @Override
         public JavaPairRDD<Integer,String> call(JavaPairRDD<Integer,String> jPairRDD) throws Exception {
                    return jPairRDD.sortByKey(false);
                  }
              });

sortedStream.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplification:

```
  JavaPairDStream<String, Long> counts = lines.countByValue();
  JavaPairDStream<Long,String> swappedPair = counts.mapToPair(Tuple2::swap);  
  JavaPairDStream<Long,String> sortedStream = swappedPair.transformToPair(s -> s.sortByKey(false));
```